# URL charset encoding google vs yahoo

Tags: ruby, url, utf-8, internationalization

What's the best way to manage i18n urls?
It's strange because google and facebook encode utf8
ex. search ★｡SмAck%2BтнAт｡★ on google

while yahoo doesn't do it.
ex. search ★｡SмAck%2BтнAт｡★ on yahoo

How do u manage utf8 urls and which libs do u use?

-- edit
I tried on Firefox and the behavior is the same, so the question is: Do you have the urls in UTF8 (/pagina/bigné.html) or do u traslitterate them in ASCII (/pagina/bign&egrave.html)? why and how?

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding your question. Both Google and Yahoo encode it correctly (you see the query correctly encoded in URL), but [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%98%85%EF%BD%A1S%D0%BCAck%252B%D1%82%D0%BDA%D1%82%EF%BD%A1%E2%98%85) doesn't return any results while [Yahoo](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=%E2%98%85%EF%BD%A1S%D0%BCAck%252B%D1%82%D0%BDA%D1%82%EF%BD%A1%E2%98%85) returns a few, indeed several pointing to Facebook.com. Please elaborate more what's the exact problem/question.

Comment: You are you to stackoverflow, so if you want help please spend a little more time on your question title and body and make them clear.

Answer (score 0):

with `URI::Escape`?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Escape.html